# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry.Key.get

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable, namevaluecollection

My below method is throwing an error:

> Error 205 An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry.Key.get

```
 static string GetConfigValue(NameValueCollection tempCollection)
    {

        string paymentDisposition = string.Empty;

        Hashtable tempCollectionHash = new Hashtable();
        foreach (string key in tempCollection.Keys)
        {
            tempCollectionHash.Add(key, tempCollection[key]);
        }


        if(tempCollectionHash.ContainsKey("Cancellation"))
            paymentDisposition = (string)tempCollectionHash["Cancellation"];

        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in tempCollectionHash)
        {
           if (DictionaryEntry.Key.Contains(" Cancellation"))
           {
               paymentDisposition = DictionaryEntry.Value.;
           }
        }

        return paymentDisposition;

    }
```

any idea why it's throwing error.

Comment: what line throws the error?

Comment: `if (**entry**.Key.Contains(" Cancellation"))`.  Not `DictionaryEntry`.  You're using the class name instead of the variable.  Same on `Value`.

Comment: Good catch @DStanley

Comment: Yes those two lines are giving error

Comment: Why are you turning your collection into a hash table anyways?  You could just scan through it looking for a match and it would perform just as well if not faster.  Using a hash table only helps if you're searching for multiple values. Or you could pass in a _dictionary_ that's already hashed by key.

Comment: Collection does not have method for contains so i am converting it to hash table

Comment: If you are doing a foreach anyway, you could check if the collection contains the value there, no need to use a hashtable :)